# How to delete a word in MS Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I opened powershell and start typing some commands and args there. I wanna delete last word I typed. Simply in `cmd` i could do it as `ctrl+backspace` but when I try the same here in powershell it appears to be `^W`. Is there some way I can eliminate the word just before the current cursor position?

Please help me in this.

Comment: I can do `ctrl+backspace` for PowerShell in its own window, but not for the one attached to VSCode (which produces `^W`)

Comment: Yes, indeed. I appologize for not mentioning. But does it have any solution?

Comment: I have no solution (I don't know if there is any special key combination for that in VSCode), but you can select the preceding word using `shift+ctrl+left arrow` then press `delete` (or `backspace`)